How to access additional resources after building with Cmake in visual studio
This is my current c++ project structure:
- \Cmake_visual_studio_test
  |
  |--\somefiles
  |     |
  |     |--test.txt
  |
  |--CmakeLists.txt
  |
  |--test.cpp
  |
  |--test.h
  |
- \out
- CMakeLists.txt
- CmakePresets.json

This structure is generated by default with CMake in Visual Studio. I created \somefiles directory with test.txt. The problem is that \somefiles cannot be accessed after compiling, and I prefer not to use hardcoded file locations. How can i copy \somefiles directory to build directory along with executable so that it can be accessed? Or is there any other more conventional way to handle this? I want to ensure that solution is compatible with other operating systems.
This is CmakeLists.txt in Cmake_visual_studio_test directory (project directory):
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for CMake_visual_studio_test, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (CMake_visual_studio_test "test.cpp" "test.h")

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.12)
  set_property(TARGET CMake_visual_studio_test PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
endif()

# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.

I used add_custom_command() in CMakeLists.txt in project directory:
add_custom_command(
    TARGET CMake_visual_studio_test POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:CMake_visual_studio_test>/somefiles"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/somefiles" "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:CMake_visual_studio_test>/somefiles"
)

But it doesn't work, i get build errors.
I just started using CMake so any help is welcome!
Update:
i modified locations and checked if they are correct:
message(STATUS "Source path: ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/somefiles")
message(STATUS "Destination path: ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/somefiles")

add_custom_command(
    TARGET CMake_visual_studio_test POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/somefiles
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/somefiles/* ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/somefiles/
)

build output message was: Error copying file ".../CMake_visual_studio_test/somefiles/*" to ".../CMake_visual_studio_test/out/build/x64-debug/CMake_visual_studio_test/somefiles/".
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

What kind of build errors do you get?

I think whatever build errors you have are independent of the add_custom_command()

The way you copy this folder is a reasonable one and it should answer the question you are asking.  With that said I usually leave the assets type folder in the source and code the executable to look for it in an alternate location when it isn't found in a path that is next to the executable like it would be when installed. An additional option is the alternate location can be passed as a command line argument to your program.

@vahancho the only error i get is "Build failed. Do you want to continue debugging?" from visual studio. I deleted code from test.cpp related to opening files (it just prints hello world), and also after i deleted add_custom_command(), it was built correctly. I forgot to note that directory called somefiles was created in build directory but its empty.

Visual Studio should have a tab containing the full and complete build-log (as text). Please look for it, and [edit] your question to include it (copy-pasted, still as text).

@drescherjm so if i understand correctly, i should keep assets along with source code and if assets are not found in folder with executable, i should search for original folder? I also want to mention that folder is created in correct location but test.txt inside it is not copied.

cmake -E copy doesn't support wildcards (*) which you are trying to use. The copy_directory command should work, but it is still unclear which "build errors" you got in that case. Please, put description into the question post itself, it should be understandable without reading the comments.
